# No HDMI after retropie restart, every time, multiple micro sd cards?

Tags: hdmi, retropie, reboot

So I install the latest image of retropie, and boot it up on my rpi3. Plug it into my hdmi arcade cab, connect to wifi, add games from pc via wifi, force audio to 3.5 or I'd have no sound, restart, play roms just fine, then here is when I have the issue...  I shut it down.  It doesn't matter how.  But after I do I have nothing when I try to restart.  I thought corrupt sd card but it happens on all that I try on.  For days I have had to reimage and go through all this over and over again.

I finally realized it's booting, but just not displaying. I can connect to it via wifi and even add roms.  I'm not a bash or Linux guy but I'm tired of reimaging.  What can I do to force this to display on my hdmi after rebooting?

Without a display, I'm not sure how to diagnose/fix this issue.  I can tell you I'm for sure over reimaging though so if anything can be done please help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the RPi is booting as stated in your question

---

- You can force the RPi to display through HDMI even if no HDMI screen is detected.
  this can be achieved by appending
  `hdmi_force_hotplug=1`
  at the end of **config.txt**

  ---

  It is not necessary but you should also append 
  `hdmi_drive=2`

  this fixes certain sound problems

  ---
- **If you still dont have any HDMI output then**

   You should append 
    `hdmi_safe=1`
  According to the documentation, this line is equivalent to setting up the following settings:

---

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
config_hdmi_boost=4
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=4
disable_overscan=0
overscan_left=24
overscan_right=24
overscan_top=24 
overscan_bottom=24
```

---

- **Insufficient power supply**

  If despite all your attempts the Raspberry Pi still not display anything on HDMI, it can come from a simple power supply problem.
  In other words, the power delivered by your power supply is enough to run your Raspberry Pi, but not to power the HDMI connection.
  So switch to a power supply of 5V, 2.5A .

  ---
- **Conclusion**
  if your RPi still doesn't show the rainbow screen then it's a hardware problem not software, good luck finding the problem.

---

Hope this helped